# Angular 7 map operator is not working with httpClient Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I got "undefined" after adding the map operator

Angular version: 7

Map import:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

With Map:

```
this.restaurantService.getRestaurants().pipe(map((restaurant:any) => restaurant.name)).subscribe((restaurants) => {
  console.log(restaurants); // undefined
});
```

> Not necessary "name" field is returning undefined at any field

Without Map

```
this.restaurantService.getRestaurants().subscribe((restaurants) => {
  console.log(restaurants); // [{...,name: 'lorem'},{...},...]
});
```

Service:

```
  getRestaurants(): Observable<_Restaurant[]> {
    return this.get(api.restaurants) as Observable<_Restaurant[]>;
  };
```

I logged the restaurant inside the map operator and I got an array which is should be object

```
 .pipe(map(restaurant => {
    console.log(restaurant); //[{},{}] !!
    return restaurant.name;
  }))
```

Any Idea why I'm getting the undefined?

Comment: @er-sho Kindly find the updated question

Comment: can you open an answer please @er-sho

Comment: Try below answer may be this can be helpful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.restaurantService
    .getRestaurants()
    .pipe(map((restaurants:any[]) => restaurants.map(restaurant => restaurant.name)));
```